# How to get flutter sdk path in android studio?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to install flutter sdk in android studio ... Everytime I install flutter sdk in android studio it again shows me the same error "Flutter sdk is not found in specified location"[This is what I'm getting everytime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clhWV.png)

Comment: configure it in your android studio. Check it out here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74170033/10618543

Answer (score 0):

Just give the path till you flutter SDK not for the flutter bin.

Set it like **D:\flutter**

Comment: Done... Thankyou

Comment: I tried the same thing earlier ...but it was not accepted ...but this time i reinstalled android studio and gave the path as D:\flutter then it worked