# How to config flutter sdk in android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I have Installed the flutter SDK. But Android studio says flutter SDK is not configured

Comment: Maybe this helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48650831/dart-sdk-is-not-configured

Answer (score 2):

Goto File -> Setting -> Language & Framework -> Flutter and add the sdk path[image]

Answer (score -1):

You should run complete Steps to Setup Flutter

1. Install Flutter and Dart plugin in Android Studios
2. Download Flutter SDK from the website
3. Run `Flutter Doctor` to complete the Flutter and Dart SDK installation.